# Parallel lines in 3D and their distance?

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the two lines are parallel. Determine the distance between them and the plane containing both lines.

$$L_{1}\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=3-2t\\y=4+t 
\\z=1-t 
\end{matrix}\right.\quad
L_{2}\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=5+2t\\y=1-t 
\\z=7+t 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I'm feeling lost.

EDIT:
They are parallel because the direction vectors are the same. $(2,-1,1)$

To calculate the normal of the plane i take $\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}2&-1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$ That is wrong. The normal shall be $(3,10,4)$. How do i calculate this?

Arbitrary point on $L_{1}(3,4,1)$.
Equation of the plane: $(x,y,z)=(3,4,1)+t(-2,1,-1)+s(2,-1,1)$

Comment: Can you find a point on both lines ? Do yo see a connection between the segment joining these points, the direction of the lines and the requested distance ? Can you find a point in the plane ? Can you find the direction of the normal to the plane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $L:\mathbf r(t)=\mathbf v_0+t\mathbf v_1$ of line $L$ requires a point $\mathbf v_0$ on $L$ and a vector $\mathbf v_1$ parallel to $L$.
$$L_1:\mathbf f(t)=\langle 3,4,1\rangle+t\langle 2,-1,1\rangle\;\;\;\;\;L_2:\mathbf g(t)=\langle 5,1,7\rangle+t\langle 2,-1,1\rangle$$
Therefore, $L_1,L_2$ are parallel because their direction vectors are the same and thus parallel. Let $d$ be the distance between $L_1,L_2$. Construct a parallelogram of area $A$ using points $\mathbf f(0),\mathbf f(1)$ on $L_1$ and points $\mathbf g(0),\mathbf g(1)$ on $L_2$.
$$A=d\cdot\vert\mathbf f(1)-\mathbf f(0)\vert=\vert(\mathbf f(1)-\mathbf f(0))\times(\mathbf g(0)-\mathbf f(0))\vert$$
$$\therefore\;\;d=\frac{\vert(\mathbf f(1)-\mathbf f(0))\times(\mathbf g(0)-\mathbf f(0))\vert}{\vert\mathbf f(1)-\mathbf f(0)\vert}=\frac{5}{6}\sqrt{30}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:This is analytic geometry problem.You have equation of lines in parametric form.  Write these equations in symmetric forms:

$L_1:$, $$\frac {x-3}{-2}=\frac{y-4}1=\frac{z-1}{-1}$$

$L_2:$  $$\frac {x-5}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-7}{1}$$

Now two lines are parallel if the ratio of their corresponding gradients(the denominators of fractions) are equal. We have:

$\frac{-2}2=\frac1{-1}=\frac{-1}1=-1$

So $L_1$ and $L_2$ are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The lines can be written in vector form as:
$\vec r=(3\vec i+ 4 \vec j+ \vec k)+t(2\vec i+ \vec j- \vec k)=\vec a+ t \vec b$ and other as $\vec r=(5 \vec i+\vec j+7\vec k)+ s(2\vec i+ \vec j- \vec k)=\vec c+ s \vec b.$ The distance between them is given by  the perpendicular projection of $\vec{AC}$ abour $\vec b$
$$d=\left|\frac{(a-\vec c)\times \vec b}{b}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{269}{6}}.$$

The direction vector of both the lines is the same $\vec b$ so they are parallel.